# How do I test string that is being passed as props jest enzyme ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the value that will be shown in the **Paragraph** element. So in order to do that I want to pass the value as a parameter in jest testing and then check if the paragraph contains the same value. When I render the component and console log that out (check image below). I will get a list of objects. But how can I access to the right data-testid and from there get the content to see if that matches with the props value.

If there is a cleaner way to do that then let me know too!

[image]

```
// SelectedValues.test.js
it('should call check props value in SelectedValue component', () => {
    const vehicleProps = [ 'car' ]
    const brandProps = [ 'tesla' ]
    const colorProps = [ 'red' ]
    const component = render(<SelectedValues curSelectVehicle={vehicleProps} curSelectBrand={brandProps} curSelectColor={colorProps}/>);

    console.log(component.find('p'))
});

// SelectedValues.js
import React from 'react';
import { 
    HeadingOne, 
    Paragraph, 
    ValueContainer, 
    ValueBlock 
} from '../../styles/SelectOptions';

export const SelectedValues = ({
    curSelectVehicle,
    curSelectBrand,
    curSelectColor
}) => {
    return (
        <ValueContainer>
            <ValueBlock>
                <HeadingOne>Selected Vehicle</HeadingOne>
                <Paragraph data-testid="select-vehicle">{curSelectVehicle}</Paragraph>
            </ValueBlock>

            <ValueBlock> 
                <HeadingOne>Selected Brand</HeadingOne>
                <Paragraph data-testid="select-brand">{curSelectBrand}</Paragraph>
            </ValueBlock>

            <ValueBlock>
                <HeadingOne>Selected Color</HeadingOne>
                <Paragraph data-test-id="select-color">{curSelectColor}</Paragraph>
            </ValueBlock>
        </ValueContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ciao, a question: why you passing props as arrays? I mean why `const vehicleProps = [ 'car' ]` instead of `'car'`? It's for test purpose?

Comment: Yes this is a jest test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/enzyme-jest-example-4osnq?file=/src/index.test.js) a working example (I used a generic `TestComponent` and instead of `Paragraph` `span` but it's the same).

The example applied for your component could be something like:

```
it('should call check props value in SelectedValue component', () => {
   const vehicleProps = [ 'car' ]
   const brandProps = [ 'tesla' ]
   const colorProps = [ 'red' ]
   const component = shallow(<SelectedValues curSelectVehicle={vehicleProps} curSelectBrand={brandProps} curSelectColor={colorProps}/>);

   const vehicle = component.findWhere(
      n => n.prop("data-testid") === "select-vehicle"
   );
   const brand = component.findWhere(
      n => n.prop("data-testid") === "select-brand"
   );
   const color = component.findWhere(
      n => n.prop("data-testid") === "select-color"
   );
   expect(vehicle.text()).toBe(vehicleProps[0]);    
   expect(brand.text()).toBe(brandProps[0]);
   expect(color.text()).toBe(colorProps[0]);
});
});
```

Note: I used `shallow`, not `render`, to call `findWhere` in `component`.

Comment: expect(component.prop('name')).toEqual('Moe') and component.setProps({ name: 'Moe' }) is this also similar as what you did above